# Volume of a rotated curve

Tags: geometry

Given a function $y = x^2 + 2$, goal is to calculate the volume of a body created by this function, when it rotates around $y$-axis, in range of $x$ = [0, 4].

[This is the function graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cMa6.png)

Now I know that this sort of problem is usually handled by basic rotation integrals, but I've been trying to use a different method, where I calculated the area under the curve using an integral, and then multiplied the given area by the angle at which the function rotates, which is $2\pi$.

Unfortunately, this gave no correct answers.
Given that the circle inside of which the function rotates has radius $r = 4$, is there a way to correlate the given area $P$ under the curve, with this circle in order to get the correct volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The volume of the bounding cylinder is:

$$V_{cyl} = \pi r^2 h = \pi 4^2 20 = 320 \pi$$

because the height is $20$.

The volume of the parabolic solid extracted from it is:

$$\int\limits_{r=0}^4 2 \pi r (20 - r^2 -2)\ dr = 160 \pi$$

and the difference is $160 \pi$.

Comment: Isn't the height 18 (4^2 + 2) ? That would change the bottom formula to 18 - r^2 - 2 in the parentheses I guess

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly discovered that your proposed method is doomed to failure. The volume of revolution doesn't just depend on the area under the curve, but depends on how that area is distributed around the axis.

For example the curves $y=x^2+2$ and $y=(x-4)^2+2$ have the same area between $x=0$ and $x=4$ but completely different volumes.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, this has been bugging me for hours, I can rest now :)